# Changing a cell in a row of a DataGrid(WPF) is changing cells in rows below

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, background

I am trying to change the `Background` of some errorneous data containing cells in a WPF `DataGrid` by using this code:

```
DataGridRow gridRow = dgInventory.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as DataGridRow;
DataGridCell cell = dgInventory.Columns[1].GetCellContent(gridRow).Parent as DataGridCell;

cell.Background = Brushes.Gray;

gridRow.IsSelected = true;
gridRow.Focus();
```

However, upon doing this, the above change of background-color change is occuring to cells in the same column, periodically after every 14 (aprox.) rows as I scroll down the `DataGrid`. It is only intended to modify the `Background` of a single row. Can someone please provide a fix to this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this:

```
<DataGrid Name="SimpleDataGrid" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" ... />
```

for scrolls in terms of physical units. It `DataGrid` *`CanContentScroll`* it is enabled by default.

For more information see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.cancontentscroll.aspx).